# shell: read: differentiate between EOF and newline

Tags: bash, shell, posix

Reading a single character, how can I tell the difference between the null `<EOF>` and `\n`?

Eg:

```
f() { read -rn 1 -p "Enter a character: " char &&
      printf "\nYou entered '%s'\n" "$char"; }
```

With a printable character:

```
$ f
Enter a character: x
You entered 'x'
```

When pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
$ f
Enter a character: 

You entered ''
```

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>:

```
$ f
Enter a character: ^D
You entered ''
$
```

Why is the output the same in the last two cases? How can I distinguish between them?

Is there a different way to do this in POSIX shell vs `bash`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `read -n "$n"` (not a POSIX feature), and if stdin is a terminal device, `read` puts the terminal out of the `icanon` mode, as otherwise `read` would only see full lines as returned by the terminal line discipline internal line editor and then reads one byte at a time until `$n` characters or a newline have been read (you may see unexpected results if invalid characters are  entered).

It reads up to `$n` character from one line. You'll also need to empty `$IFS` for it not to strip IFS characters from the input.

Since we leave the `icanon` mode, `^D` is no longer special. So if you press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, the `^D` character will be read.

You wouldn't see eof from the terminal device unless the terminal is somehow disconnected. If stdin is another type of file, you may see eof (like in `: | IFS= read -rn 1; echo "$?"` where stdin is an empty pipe, or with redirecting stdin from `/dev/null`)

`read` will return 0 if `$n` characters (bytes not forming part of valid characters being counted as 1 character) or a full line have been read.

So, in the special case of only one character being requested:

```
if IFS= read -rn 1 var; then
  if [ "${#var}" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo an empty line was read
  else
    printf %s "${#var} character "
    (export LC_ALL=C; printf '%s\n' "made of ${#var} byte(s) was read")
  fi
else
  echo "EOF found"
fi
```

Doing it POSIXly is rather complicated.

That would be something like (assuming an ASCII-based (as opposed to EBCDIC for instance) system):

```
readk() {
  REPLY= ret=1
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    saved_settings=$(stty -g)
    stty -icanon min 1 time 0 icrnl
  fi
  while true; do
    code=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null | od -An -vto1 | tr -cd 0-7)
    [ -n "$code" ] || break
    case $code in
      000 | 012) ret=0; break;; # can't store NUL in variable anyway
      (*) REPLY=$REPLY$(printf "\\$code");;
    esac
    if expr " $REPLY" : ' .' > /dev/null; then
      ret=0
      break
    fi
  done
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    stty "$saved_settings"
  fi
  return "$ret"
}
```

Note that we return only when a full character has been read. If the input is in the wrong encoding (different from the locale's encoding), for instance if your terminal sends `é` encoded in iso8859-1 (0xe9) when we expect UTF-8 (0xc3 0xa9), then you may enter as many `é` as you like, the function will not return. `bash`'s `read -n1` would return upon the second 0xe9 (and store both in the variable) which is a slightly better behaviour.

If you also wanted to read a `^C` character upon <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (instead of letting it kill your script; also for `^Z`, `^\`...), or 
`^S`/`^Q` upon <kbd>Ctrl+S/Q</kbd> (instead of flow control), you could add a `-isig -ixon` to the `stty` line. Note that `bash`'s `read -n1` doesn't do it either (it even restores `isig` if it was off).

That will not restore the tty settings if the script is killed (like if you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. You could add a `trap`, but that would potentially override other `trap`s in the script.

You could also use `zsh` instead of `bash`, where `read -k` (which predates `ksh93` or `bash`'s `read -n/-N`) reads one character from the terminal and handles `^D` by itself (returns non-zero if that character is entered) and doesn't treat newline specially.

```
if read -k k; then
  printf '1 character entered: %q\n' $k
fi
```

Comment: I love your answers, @Stéphane Chazelas. 
If we leave icanon mode and can capture `^D`, then [why can't we capture `\n`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383197/143394)?

Comment: @TomHale, see edit if you can use `zsh`. For the POSIX approach, you can take care of newline in the 012 case.

Comment: With `-icannon` a `ctrl-s` (as one example of un-managed input) will put the code in suspension. That will block the TTY until a `ctrl-q` is issued. There are several other keys that will not be read but will afect the tty, as an aditional example `ctrl-C`.

Comment: Not a big issue but: It will be wise to change the `printf "\\$code"` to `printf '%s' "\\$code"` as the value of `$code` could be anything if the `-t` test fails.

Comment: Why do you need `REPLY=$REPLY……` if the function is reading a one character anyway ?

Comment: @Arrow, re: ^C/^S, note that bash's `read -n1` doesn't reset isig/ixon either. It seems reasonable to still allow the user to interrupt/quit/suspend the script or suspend output here. I've still added a not to that effect. Thanks.

Comment: @Arrow, `$code` contains the 3 digit octal code of a single byte read from stdin (whether stdin is a terminal device or not). So it's either `printf "\\$code"` or `printf %b "\0$code"`

Comment: @Arrow, re: `REPLY=$REPLY...`, `dd` reads one byte at a time, so we need to keep reading until the end of the character as characters can be made of more than one byte (most are in UTF-8) like `read -n1` does. The `expr` command is the one checking that a full character has been read (matches `.`). If the input is in the wrong encoding (different from the locale's), that may never return. Maybe I should add a note to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

In `f()` change the `%s` to `%q`:

```
f() { read -rn 1 -p "Enter a character: " char && \
      printf "\nYou entered '%q'\n" "$char"; }
f;f
```

Output, if the user enters a *newline*, then '*Ctrl-D*':

```
Enter a character: 

You entered ''''
Enter a character: ^D
You entered '$'\004''
```

---

From `man printf:

```
 %q       ARGUMENT is printed in a format that can be reused as shell input, 
          escaping non-printable characters with the proposed POSIX $'' syntax.
```

Comment: How do I get the newline case to show `You entered '$'\012''` vs the null character it's currently showing?

Comment: @TomHale The newline terminates the input, it isn't part of it

Comment: @TomHale You can capture the newline if you add `-d ''`

Comment: Not with: `f() { read -rd '' -n1 -p "Enter a character: " char &&       printf "\nYou entered: %q\n" "$char"; }` I raised a [separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383197/143394) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you run `read -rn1` in Bash, and hit `^D`, it's treated as the literal control character, not an EOF condition. The control character just isn't visible when printed, so it doesn't appear with `printf "'%s'"`.
Piping the output to something like `od -c` would show it, as would `printf "%q"` which other answers already mentioned.

With actually nothing as input, the result is different, here empty even with `printf "%q"`:

```
$ f()  { read -rn 1  x ; printf "%q\n" "$x"; }
$ printf "" | f
''
```

The newline isn't returned by `read` here for two reasons. First, it's the default line delimiter of read, and hence returned as output. Second, it's also part of the default `IFS`, and `read` removes leading and trailing whitespace if they are part of `IFS`.

So, we need `read -d` to change the delimiter from the default, *and* make `IFS` empty:

```
$ g() { IFS= read -rn 1 -d '' x ; printf "%q\n" "$x"; }
$ printf "\n" | g
$'\n'
```

`read -d ""` makes the delimiter effectively the NUL byte, which means this still doesn't tell the difference between an input of nothing, and an input of a NUL byte:

```
$ printf "" | g
''
$ printf "\000" | g
''
```

Though with nothing as input, `read` returns false, so we could check `$?` to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -r var
status=$?
echo "\$var='$var':\$?=$status"
```

The newline and Ctrl-D cases are distinguished by the status variable.

In case of newline, the status is true (0) whilst when the Ctrl-D is given,
the status is false (1)

Comment: Not with `-n 1`. The status is 0.

Comment: `-n 1` and status 0 indicates a `\n' which is [mysteriously removed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383197/143394).