# bash: read: how to capture '\n' (newline) character?

Tags: bash, shell

Can I use `read` to capture the `\n` `\012` or newline character?

Define test function:

```
f() { read -rd '' -n1 -p "Enter a character: " char &&
      printf "\nYou entered: %q\n" "$char"; }
```

Run the function, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
$ f;
Enter a character: 

You entered: ''
```

Hmmm. It's a null string.

How do I get my expected output:

```
$ f;
Enter a character:

You entered: $'\012'
$
```

**I want the same method to be able to capture `^D` or `\004`.**

If `read` can't do it, what is the work around?

Comment: To do this in POSIX `sh`, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383196/143394).

Comment: You need to prefix the read into a variable with `IFS=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read 1 character, use `-N` instead, which reads one character always and doesn't do `$IFS` processing:

```
read -rN1 var
```

`read -rn1` reads one record up to one character and still does `$IFS` processing (and newline is in the default value of `$IFS` which explains why you get an empty result even though you read NUL-delimited records). You'd use it instead to limit the length of the record you read.

In your case, with NUL-delimited records (with `-d ''`), `IFS= read -d '' -rn1 var` would work the same as `bash` cannot store a NUL character in its variables anyway, so `printf '\0' | read -rN1 var` would leave `$var` empty and return a non-zero exit status.

To be able to read arbitrary characters including NUL, you'd use the `zsh` shell instead where the syntax is:

```
read -k1 'var?Enter a character: '
```

(no need for `-r` or `IFS=` there. However note that `read -k` reads *from the terminal* (`k` is for *key*; zsh's `-k` option predates bash's and even ksh93's `-N` by decades). To read from stdin, use `read -u0 -k1`).

Example (here pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> to enter a NUL character):

```
$ read -k1 'var?Enter a character: '
Enter a character: ^@
$ printf '%q\n' $var
$'\0'
```

Note that to be able to read a *character*, `read` may have to read more than one byte. If the input starts with the first byte of multi-byte character, it will read at least one more byte, so you could end up with `$var` containing something that the shell considers having a length greater than 1 if the input contains byte sequences not forming valid characters.

For instance in a UTF-8 locale:

```
$ printf '\xfc\x80\x80\x80\x80XYZ' | bash -c 'read -rN1 a; printf "<%q>\n" "$a" "${#a}"; wc -c'
<$'\374\200\200\200\200X'>
<6>
2
$ printf '\xfc\x80\x80\x80\x80XYZ' | zsh -c 'read -u0 -k1 a; printf "<%q>\n" $a $#a; wc -c'
<$'\374'$'\200'$'\200'$'\200'$'\200'X>
<6>
2
```

In UTF-8, 0xFC is the first byte of a 6-byte long character, the 5 other ones meant to have the 8th bit set and the 7th bit unset, however we provide only 4. `read` still reads that extra `X` to try and find the end of the character which ends up in `$var` along with those 5 bytes that don't form a valid character and end up being counted as one character each.

Answer (score 5):

`bash` builtin `read` can do this:

```
read -rd $'\0' -p ... -n 1
printf '\nYou typed ASCII %02x\n' "'$REPLY"
```

(this piece of code won't work with multi-byte characters)

Notice how I didn't put what is read in variable `char` as you did. This is because doing so would remove the characters in IFS from `char`. With a standard IFS, you wouldn't be able to differentiate between space, tab and newline.